# How can I make a batch file detect a keypress while something is running from it?

Tags: batch-file

I made an automatic ping batch file, and I'm looking for a way to stop it and ask for a new address to ping if I press, I dunno, spacebar (Without prompting) so I don't have to CTRL+C and open it again.

This is **the** code so far.

```
@echo off
:M
cls
set /p D="Ping IP or URL: "
cls
:loop
ping "%D%"
choice /c:0z /t 1 /d 0
if errorlevel 2 goto M
goto loop
```

Edit: Noodles' answer worked 50%, since the ping stops even if I don't press Z.

Comment: I presume you searched here for `[batch-file] key press` and checked quite a few of the 837 existing questions before posting? I'm also guessing you didn't read through the [help/behavior] page about greetings, signatures and salutations being discouraged here, either. This isn't a social site.

Comment: @Ken White I kind of searched, but I found "vbs", "python", "C#"... And about the batch results, nothing related at all.

Comment: I just gave you the **exact search phrase**, and when I used it just before writing my previous comment there were 837 results (which is also **exactly what I said** in my previous comment).

Comment: Maybe THAT was my problem... Gotta learn about the search terms and variables then.
Got a page to it? I'm prone to getting lost.

Comment: When you do a search and the results show, there's a text control containing your search phrase, with a big blue *Search* button to the right of it. Right next to that *Search* button is a highlighted link labeled *Advanced search tips*. Click it. :-)

Comment: I've tried searching "batch file keypress" before I wrote the post, without [].
Ian's INT decreased by 2.

Comment: I don't know what *INT* means; I'm presuming you mean the downvote you received? It wasn't from me. My entire interaction here to this point is the edit I made and the three (now four) comments I've posted.

Comment: INT: "Intellect", not the "integer" variable. Lel.

Comment: Since you have trouble searching, here you go Mr. God in my world. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+key+press

Comment: Under ping line `choice /c:0z /t 1 /d 0` then `if errorlevel 2 goto ALabelAtTopOfFile`. z stops it. Put a label at top of file.

Comment: Your code worked here. You just have to press Z at the right time as it's a keyboard read not reading stdin.

Comment: Um... Is it relevant if I said I use Windows XP? I've read the "CHOICE" command was removed, but it returned at Vista.